# How can I get the first part of the API Deployment URL from inside cloud formation template?

Tags: api, aws-cloudformation

https://u1i7vf9mnl.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1

How can I get the u1i7vf9mnl portion of the URL from inside of the cloudformation template as a Ref or Fn::GetAtt or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the variable `ServerlessRestApi`? It works for us like this:

```
Outputs:    
    EncryptURL:
      Description: "Encrypt endpoint URL for Stage environment"
      Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Stage/encrypt"
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Yep! That was it! I had to reference the actual RestApi resource. I was referencing the method resource.

Comment: @mutant_city Cool!